# Bluemix, Mobile Client Access: Does MCA service support RESTAPI accessing for web application?

Tags: mobile, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I deployed a java application in bluemix container using ibmliberty image and authorize by using Mobile Client Access service with facebook authorization.(i am not using mobile client), now there is an requirement which need to access the web application using restapi,does mca service support it?

Comment: Please make your question more specific. What are you trying to do? What is trying to access the web application? Why? How? And what do you mean that you are using Mobile Client Access but not using mobile client?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly sure what you're trying to ask, so here's a general answer. MCA implements OAuth2 protocol, which allows any web application to use it regardless of the technology stack.

Below are some resources that explain how it works:

1. Here's a blog article demonstrating an example of how to protect a web app using MCA. It will show you how to retrieve the **identity token** to retrieve user identity information, such as full name, age, country, timezone, profile picture, etc., and the **access token** to access resources protected by the Mobile Client Access service on behalf of your users:

   https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2016/07/protect-web-apps-with-mobile-client-access/
2. Here's the documentation on Bluemix:

   https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobileaccess/overview.html